# How can I change the default action method inside the ActionInvokeMethod of the ControllerActionInvoker class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

How can I change the default action method inside the `ActionInvokeMethod` of the `ControllerActionInvoker` class?

Comment: It would help if you described the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

This is not controlled in that function.  This comes from your RouteTable.

For example:

```
routeCollection.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {action = "Index", id = (string) null}, new {controller = @"[^\.]*"});
```

Note there that the anonymous object has action = "Index"

This tells the routing engine that if action does not exist, set it's value to "Index".

This is probably the very route you want to modify in your RouteTable.  If I changed this in my app to "SomeOtherAction" that would be the default action that would fire.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This call is found in your Global.asax in the RegisterRoutes method!